# Openssl install broken after dist upgrade

Tags: 22.04, openssl

Recently upgraded to 22.04 and I've notice my openssl install is now broken.
I've tried an apt-get --reinstall install openssl libssl3 and the issue remains.

On startup of openssl I'm getting the error:

```
FATAL: Startup failure (dev note: apps_startup()) for openssl
40D7A905CA7F0000:error:07800069:common libcrypto routines:provider_conf_init:provider section error:../crypto/provider_conf.c:298:
40D7A905CA7F0000:error:0700006D:configuration file routines:module_run:module initialization error:../crypto/conf/conf_mod.c:243:module=providers, value=provider_sect retcode=-1
```

and I'm not getting anything other than source code and pull requests when I search for any of those lines.
Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a possible error in your OpenSSL configuration file. Have you made any edits to your config file? The standard configuration file is in /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf. Can you share it? Do you have the `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable set - and if so what to? If that is set and points at anything other than the standard config file please share that file instead.

Comment: Thanks Matt, on closer inspection my [provider_sect] section was, for want of a better word, fucked.

Comment: The 22.04 uses OpenSSL 3. You installation might need 1.1

Comment: Getting similar issues after the recent update.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

openssl will create default cnf file/